# How do I have helm select the literal text I typed in, not one of the options in the menu?

Tags: helm, helm-selection

I've been getting deeper into org, and I've started using more properties. I have helm set up, so when I try to set an org property, helm is what is used to select both the property name and property value.

Helm prefills the selection list with the property names it knows about, and propery values it's seen before, which is normally great. But sometimes, I want to select a property name that's a substring of an existing property name (e.g., instead of the default `CATEGORY` property, I want to set the `CAT` property), or a property value that's a substring of an existing property value (e.g., a property value is `Brian Jones`, but I want to set one to `Ian Jones`), or I want to set a property to something that's a valid regex value (e.g., I want to set a single period, `.`, as a  property value).

Sometimes (e.g., in `#'helm-find-files`), at the top of the list is the literal value you've typed in. But I don't see that in these org property prompts. How can I get them to appear?

Comment: Which helm version are you using?

Comment: There is a short command for this, like C-M-j or something. Read the manual.